# why i get [native code] when use my function

Tags: javascript, native-code

I'm trying to create a function which inverts string's letters case, so the string "John" will be "jOHN".

Here is my code:

```
const upperLower = function(string){
  let newString ="", newChar ="";

  for(let i = 0; i < string.length; i++){
    if (string.charAt(i) === " "){
      newChar = " "
    } else if (string.charAt(i) === string.charAt(i).toUpperCase()){
      newChar = string.charAt(i).toLowerCase;
    } else {
      newChar = string.charAt(i).toUpperCase;
    }
    newString += newChar;
  }
  return newString;
}
```

When I'm using it, what i get is something like this:

```
"function toLowerCase() { [native code] }function toUpperCase() { [native code] }function toUpperCase() { [native code] }function toUpperCase() { [native code] } function toLowerCase() { [native code] }function toUpperCase() { [native code] }function toUpperCase() { [native code] }function toUpperCase() { [native code] }function toUpperCase() { [native code] }function toLowerCase() { [native code] }"
```

Where i'm getting wrong, and why my result looks like that? Thanks

Comment: Please look at the "duplicate" link. It's not just the same task, your errors are similar as well.

Comment: `newChar = string.charAt(i).toLowerCase` you forgot to add `()`, therefore, you are not invoking toLowerCase, but assigning the variable `newCHar` with the function.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're not actually calling `toLowerCase` or `toUpperCase` in your `else` conditions. You're referencing them, so you get the default string representation of the functions.

```
{newChar = string.charAt(i).toLowerCase}      // <=- Not calling
else {newChar = string.charAt(i).toUpperCase} // <=- Not calling
```

You need the `()` to actually call the function, like you do with `toUpperCase()`.

Unrelated, but the formatting of your code makes it quite difficult to read.

Making it easier to read makes it easier to debug and think about. If everything wasn't all mushed up the error would be *very* clear.

```js
const upperLower = function(string){
  let newString ="", newChar ="";
  for (let i=0; i < string.length; i++) {
    if (string.charAt(i) === " ") {
      newChar = " "
    } else if (string.charAt(i) === string.charAt(i).toUpperCase()) {
      newChar = string.charAt(i).toLowerCase()
    } else {
      newChar = string.charAt(i).toUpperCase()
    }
   newString += newChar;
  }

  return newString;
}

console.log(upperLower("hELLO"));
```